# Need a Java program to run my programs

Tags: java

I have Mac OS 10.6.8. I started taking Stanfords CS106A class on my own to learn Java. Their Eclipse program works fine for their assignments. However, in trying to do the problems in the textbook 'The Art & Science of Java' by Eric Roberts (source code downloaded from his site www.aw.com/cssuport/) they won't run in Eclipse (at least I haven't been able to do so) and double clicking the source code brings up Xcode which also doesn't work.

I went to the http://jtf.acm.org/ web page and downloaded the following

```
tutorial.pdf    
ecutive-summary.pdf     
acm.jar JAR archive containing the acm packages
acm.zip
```

The tutorial doesn't show how to install the program. Double clicking the acm.jar gives an error message which it says to check the console which tells me nothing.. Double clicking the acm.zip opens a file with lots of files of classes.

What can I use to run my problem programs? and, how do I install it?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: *"they won't run in Eclipse (at least I haven't been able to do so)"* Eclipse is capable of compiling anything that can be compiled from the command line.  If that is what the course uses, I'd stick with it.  As to the ACM API, AFAIR it is a graphics API, and does not 'run separately'.  Instead you need to add it to the compile & run-time class-path of the app.  Search those concepts in the Eclipse help and get back to us with a more specific question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried typing in a terminal:

```
java -jar acm.jar
```

btw you will have to cd to the directory the acm.jar file is contained in. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, assuming the source files are contained in the zip, you could extract them, create a new Project in Eclipse and choose the folder in which you extracted them as the source of your project. Then you should be able to inspect how the program works and also compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse for all of your projects, including the Roberts problems, while learning java. Stanford provides a special build of eclipse to mesh with their course, but it functions just the same as the public build, plus a few extra features for their students to submit assignments.

To organize your files in eclipse, maybe create one new project titled CS106a and another titled Roberts. To start a new program, highlight the project you want, then do File > New > Class. Use the src folder and the default package for now. This isn't the neatest or most technical solution, but it will get you up and running, and is adequate for many of the simple problems you'll be tackling in the text and in the lecture series.

Also, you'll need to import acm.jar for each project. You can do this by highlighting the project and clicking Project > Properties > Project Build Path > Add External JARs.

To run the downloaded examples from the textbook's website, import those files into eclipse under the Roberts project. If you open one of the .java files and try to run, you will get an error. However, add a new class, give it the name of this java file, then paste the entire text of the java file into the new one. Save and run. This works fine; I assume there must be a cleaner way to import something as a new class in a project, but I haven't figured it out.